# 2.8 Set up auto texture saving with saving of file

Tags: texture-painting

Is there any add-on or any plan in the works to autosave texture maps that are being painted with texture paint to a temp folder when the project itself is saved? This seems like a huge oversight when it comes to workflow as exporting the texture after each change is a bit cumbersome. It's also a bit disheartening after a crash to see that the preview for the texture is saved somewhere with all changes, but the texture itself is not.

Edit: This also applies to textures/masks that are created for the texture paint brush. After a close and reopen, they are gone.

Comment: Since 2.8, when you save your file but haven't saved your images, Blender asks you if you want to save them, and it looks like in this case it automatically packs them, so I'm not sure about your question

Comment: I haven't seen that prompt.Although I just had an instance where textures were not exported, blender crashed, on re-open the texture recovered part of my work. So maybe autosave is doing it but save with ctrl+s isn't?

Comment: maybe you enabled File > External Data > Automatically Pack Into Blend, in that case I guess the texture is saved with the blend.1